# UITextField crashing after 7 keystrokes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField. When I type in it, it works fine, until I type in the 7th keystroke, at which point it crashes. The crash doesn't show up in XCode - there's no indication that it crashed at all. No crash log or anything of the sort. I'm running this on an iPad.

EDIT: Disconnecting from XCode means I get a crash log:

```
App[12345] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1f5bf200> identifier: Suspending process: App[12345] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:26 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}
```

Comment: I suggest performing the same series of steps in Instruments to rule out that there isn't some memory-related issue occurring. Can you please post the code related to your textField, TextField delegate methods, keyboard hide/show?

Comment: Does it crash on a certain key?

Comment: are you using shouldChangeCharactersInRange of TextField Delegate...?

Comment: No certain key - different keys each time. I'm not using that delegate method, no.

Comment: Try to disable the auto correction. Maybe this is broken. I had this once on the simulator.

Comment: @dasdorn that solved it - thanks. Not sure what the problem was - must be an Apple bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable the auto correction. Maybe this is broken. I had this once on the simulator.